# ifconfig: command not found

Tags: networking, 20.04

I've been trying to use the tool **HT-WPS-BREAKER** on Ubuntu 20.04, I run it as it should be, then I select the second choice which is `Attack automatically with Airodump-ng. (WEP/WPS{WPA/WPA2})` but after that, I keep getting the following error

```
HT-WB.sh: line 724: ifconfig: command not found
```

I've tried googling the problem but yet I've found no solution.

[image: an attached image that shows the error more accurately]

Comment: @heynnema sorry, i use it for learning purposes sir, exactly in pentesting, i thing i used pentesting as a tag.

Comment: Install `gnome-nettool`.

Comment: @heynnema it WORKED!!, thank you soo much <3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem following [heynnema's comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2149288). The solution was to install `gnome-nettool` package.